# How to run Shiny Server on linux using remote acces?

Tags: linux, r, remote-access, shiny, shiny-server

I'm trying to put in production my shiny app. I can run my shiny app locally on my Windows machine, from R. However, since we need to use Linux to deploy the app over the web, we decided to use a Linux server for that. We access this Linux server remotely, from our local machines (running Windows).

I followed the instruction at the RStudio website, and successful installed Shine Server on the Linux server. Its's running on it. I don't know what to do next. So, my question is: what should I do next? Please, remember that I access the Linux server remotely (using puty). Also, I have almost no knowledge of Linux.

Any guidance on what to do next is very welcome.

Some info that may be useful: 
I use a Ubuntu 12.04.3
I ran as root (I think, but I can use sudo, for sure).
Another person has access to this server besides me.
We use R 3.0.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can follow the instructions here: 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/shiny-discuss/NuZp0ziVXvw/BXHcIoXThnoJ

Short answer:

```
# this is all one line
sudo wget\
  https://raw.github.com/rstudio/shiny-server/master/config/upstart/shiny-server.conf\
  -O /etc/init/shiny-server.conf

# Start the server
sudo start shiny-server
```

Then just open a browser and point to it

Comment: Hi @Ricardo Saporta, I got an error: 404 not found, And "/etc/init/shiny-server.conf: the schema is empty [or lacking] (I'm translating from Portuguese, so maybe not exactly this error message in English). Any clue?

Comment: It worked. I was misunderstending the "\" as a literal character, and it was just pointing that there was a break line